# Update field using the existing value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Working with the following MongoDB version (`package.json` content):

```
"mongodb": "^3.0.2"
```

And I have the following code:

```
const addValue = 10;

await db.db('dbname').collection('collname').updateOne({
        bar: bar
    }, {
        $set: {
            foo: foo
        }
     }
);
```

I want to set the variable foo to the old value of foo + the addValue variable. Something like this in pseudo code:

```
$set: {
    foo: foo + addValue 
}
```

When implementing this code I get the following I get a referenceError:

```
 C:\Users\wille\Desktop\Projects\nv\server\XXX_playground.js:28
             foo: foo  + addValue
                         ^

 **ReferenceError**: foo is not defined
     at Timeout.test [as _onTimeout] (C:\Users\wille\Desktop\Projects\nv\server\XXX_playground.js:28:26)
     at ontimeout (timers.js:424:11)
     at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:288:5)
     at listOnTimeout (timers.js:251:5)
     at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:211:10) PS C:\Users\wille\Desktop\Projects\nv\server>
```

I simply first could query the foo variable with `findOne` store it in a variable, and then use it in the `updateOne`. However, this would result in 2 queries and seems a bit suboptimal.

### Question:

Is there a way of doing this in one query?

Comment: The pseudo code should work... Are there any errors using that?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, throws an error indeed

Comment: Can you include that as an [edit] to your question?

Comment: Working on it have it in a construction where I cannot read the error, will move it in test environment 1sec

Comment: It is just a referenceError which seems reasonable

Comment: Are you always just adding numbers?

Comment: Yes it are always 100% numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose's [`$inc`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operator accepts increment values as the values of the object passed to it:

```js
const addValue = 10;

await db.db('dbname').collection('collname').updateOne({
    bar: bar
}, {
    $inc: {
        foo: addValue // the value you want to increment by
    }
});
```

Comment: That works indeed, thanks! I actually knew that operator but thought it was for something else :P.

Comment: I also never really used it to it's full potential, I always just did findOne -> update